# View Model implementation - less fields than in entities

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I have two entities: `Person` and `Quote` (in one to many relationship)

**Person:**

```
 public class Person
 {
    public int PersonID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(20]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [StringLength(30]
    public string Relation { get; set; }

    public byte[] Image { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string ImageMimeType { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Quote> Quotes { get; set; }
}
```

**Quote:**

```
public class Quote
{
    public int QuoteID { get; set; }

    public int PersonID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(200)]
    public string QuoteName { get; set; }

    [StringLength(400)]
    public string Context { get; set; }

    public DateTime? Date { get; set; }

    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
}
```

I want to make a ViewModel for displaying quotes in short format - I need just a few properties - `Person Name`, `QuoteName` and `Person Image`. I could do something casual like they're showing in every ASP.NET MVC tutorial:

```
 public class QuoteViewModel
 {
    public IEnumerable<Quote> Quotes { get; set; }
 }
```

Is there a better way rather than creating IEnumerable with type of `Quote` and loading all properties?

How about creating `QuoteShort` model and making `QuoteViewModel` as `IEnumerable<QuoteShort> QuotesShort`.

In controller I would map every 3 fields from repository to `QuoteShort` and add it to `QuotesShort` IEnumerable (even though I don't know how to persist them to `QuotesShort` IEnumerable )

Some examples appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a `QuoteShort` ViewModel with just the few properties you need, and then have your view expect `IEnumerable<QuoteShort>` as its model. You don't necessarily have to wrap that up in another container.

If you have this:

```
public class QuoteShort{

    public Person Person {get;set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    // etc
}
```

You can do this in the controller:

```
var quotes = //however you get your list of quotes
var model = (from q in quotes select new QuoteShort
                { Person = q.Person, Name = q.Name /*etc*/ }).ToList();

return View(model);
```

Comment: Good hint about view expecting IEnumerable and thanks for the linq example. Entity Framework made a proper inner join.

Answer (score 2):

What about something like

```
public class QuotesShortViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<QuoteShortViewModel> QuotesShort { get; set; }
}

public class QuoteShortViewModel
{
    // ... the properties you need
}
```

Create a `View` that receives a QuotesShortViewModel and iterates through the list, rendering the short quotes as it pleases you.

[`AutoMapper`](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) is useful to map between Models and ViewModels in your controllers.

Comment: When using AutoMapper, you can use the Project().To<QuoteShortViewModel>() extension to only retrieve the required properties from the database.